Problem locations occurring after parsing C++ with Rascal and clair
I am parsing a list of cpp files using a simple Rascal script that uses the createM3AndAstFromCppFile function from the clair package to parse the C++ code and generate a M3 model. Unfortunately, in the generated M3 model, I get a few of the following problem types occurring several thousands of times:
"problem:///{problem_id}?message=Invalid%20redefinition%20of%20the%20name%20cpp_to_com"
"problem:///{problem_id}?message=Attempt%20to%20use%20symbol%20failed:%20size"
"cpp+method:///9dd81a0b-eb0b-43ec-a2b2-44f9beb31e3d/operator%20()(const.cpp::uuid.&)?message=Invalid%20type%20encountered%20in:%20hash%20"
I am using Rascal (0.34.2) + Clair (0.12.0) through VSCode.
I have tried looking up information online, expanding the lists of standard libraries and include dirs that the function takes as input, and using different versions of both Rascal and clair, expecting that that might resolve the issues. However, all of those problems still occur in the generated M3.

My first step is always to see if the error also is produced by the IDE or LSP server for C++. If that's the case then at least we know that both clair and the IDE are badly configured, or the error is real in the code. If that's not the case, then the include path is probably different for clair. I'd focus on differences like: same Compiler (GCC, clang, Microsoft, Intel), Library dependencies, and versions of those.

Any news on your progress?
